# Error while creating an extension in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

In the PostgreSQL client (`postgres`):

```
create extension addme;
```

Error:

> ERROR:  extension "addme" has no installation script nor update path for version "0.0.1"

How can I resolve this error while creating an extension in PostgreSQL?

How do I resolve this error and create an extension? Which script is to be installed and which path is to be updated and how can I come up with a solution?

Comment: The error explains the problem very well, at least to somebody who has read [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-extensions.html).

Comment: How is this not a duplicate? After 15 years and [170,908 PostgreSQL questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql) questions.

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags. Apache AGE has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is pretty much self explanatory, as per the error message, the extension `addme` lacks the required installation or update scripts for version "0.0.1".

For detailed instructions and to ensure compatibility with your PostgreSQL version, consult the [extensions documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-extensions.html) of postgresql. Try generating the extension again after you have the necessary scripts and have adjusted the extension's script or path. Make sure you use the appropriate PostgreSQL SQL command or tool, such as the `CREATE EXTENSION` command or pgAdmin, to create extensions. You may fix the problem and successfully add the "addme" extension to PostgreSQL by following these instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The error message which you are getting shows that the PostgreSQL extension "addme" is not currently stored on the system. There are two ways in which you can resolve this error:

1. First one is that you use the CREATE EXTENSION statement. Just type in the following command:

   CREATE EXTENSION addme;
2. The second method is that you build the extension from the source code. This would allow you to have the latest version of the extension but the downside is that this method is a bit complex. You would need to install the code from the project's website and then build it.

Comment: while running "create extension addme;" that error appears as mentioned in question

Answer (score 0):

To successfully install your extension, you will need to meet the following minimum requirements:

- A control file named `addme.control`.
- An installation script named `addme-0.0.1.sql`.

Please ensure that the file names match exactly as specified. For a more comprehensive understanding, refer to the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are facing ‘extension "addme" has no installation script nor update path for version "0.0.1"’ is due to the missing installation script.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make sure you install the extension properly, the error shown is specific and clear that you haven't installed the extension yet, or you maybe have installed it somewhere that postgres couldn't find it, otherwise please provide more information for the steps you followed for installing the extension.

Also make sure you follow the documentation for installixng extensions, and let me know how it goes with you!.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty self-explanatory error. Whatever extension you are trying to create needs an installation script and an update path.

The installation script that executes during the extension installation process, and the update path to control and handle updates of the extension. You can find more details in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-extensions.html)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have no installation script to create/install the particular extension.

For any extension, we need some essential files,

- addme.control
- addme--0.0.1.sql

Make sure, your file names should match the version.

Check out the official documentation for more about [Extensions in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-extensions.html).

Answer (score 0):

The error states very clearly that the extension `addme` does not have the necessary installation or update scripts for version `0.0.1`.

In order to resolve the issue:

1. you need to have an extension called `addme`, and
2. you need an installation script called `addme--0.0.1.sql`

But the best option would be that you consult the documentation, where you could get the most accurate information.

I hope this will sort out your issue!

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because your installation scripts are missing. So, in order to resolve this error:

- You need to create a control file such as **addme.control**.
- Create an installation script with SQL commands such as **addme--0.0.1.sql**.
  -After putting these files in the postgres extension directory, you need to reload the postgreSQL using this command:

```
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

- Then create the extension with this command:

```
CREATE EXTENSION addme;
```

Answer (score -1):

The error message you received indicates that the extension you are trying to install, "addme", does not have an installation script or an update path defined for version "0.0.1". In order to resolve this error, you will need to provide the necessary installation scripts and update paths for your extension.

The following steps should resolve this error:

- Create a directory for your extension:
  You can create a directory for your extension in the PostgreSQL shared extension directory. The default location for this directory is `/usr/share/postgresql/extension` on Linux systems. You can create a subdirectory in this location for your extension.
- You will need to create an installation script for your extension that specifies how it should be installed. This script should be named `addme--0.0.1.sql` (assuming that the version of your extension is 0.0.1) and should be placed in the directory you created in step 1. The installation script should contain SQL commands that create any necessary tables, functions, or other database objects that your extension requires.
- Once you have created the installation script and any necessary update paths, you can register your extension with PostgreSQL by running the `CREATE EXTENSION` command. For example, you can run the following command to create the "addme" extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION addme;
```

This command should execute successfully now, since you have provided the necessary installation script and update paths for your extension.

Ref:
[Package installation Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-extensions.html)

Comment: This answer looks like mostly ChatGPT